# How can I find additional cubic roots of a 2x2 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, radicals, factoring, diagonalization

I have a matrix 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -3.5 & 4.5 \\
    4.5 & -3.5 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am tasked with finding 3 cubic roots of the matrix. I was able to find one using the characteristic equation $(-3.5 - \lambda)^2 - 4.5^2 = 0$, or equivalently $  \lambda^2 + 7 \lambda  - 8 = 0$

I found eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = -8, \lambda_2 = 1$, with respective eigenvectors
$$
   \begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    -1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
and 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Doing the calculation 
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    -1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}*
\begin{bmatrix}
    -8 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}^{1/3}
*
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    -1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$
Gives me   \begin{bmatrix}
    -.5 & 1.5 \\
    1.5 & -.5 \\
    \end{bmatrix}

Which is a correct cubic root, but I am not certain how to get two other cubic roots. I know previously I have taken a $\pm \lambda$ due to the factor $(-\lambda)^2  = 
\lambda^2$, but those seemed to only work in cases where the power is even. With a cubic root it seems as though the eigenvalue matrix can't be along the lines of \begin{bmatrix}
    \pm(-8)^{1/3} & 0 \\
    0 & \pm 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
because the negative sign will stick around due to the odd power.

Comment: There will be nine cube roots in all. If you only want three, a cheap trick is to multiply your cube root by the three complex cube roots of unity.

Comment: Thank you! I think this should suffice